# Network Video Recording Software

Tags: video, networking, camera

I am looking for an NVR software.

1. Needs to support [UniFi Video cameras](https://www.ubnt.com/products/#surveillance)
2. Support RTSP (real time streaming protocol)
3. Fulltime recording, scheduled recording, and motion recording
4. UI to monitor/setup NVR (preferably web based) that is accessible on the LAN
5. Email alerts, on schedule, when motion was detected
6. Don't have a big preference for OS
7. Price is not much of an issue either

Comment: Which OS must this software run on? Any price limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently converted my network camera to use [ZoneMinder](https://zoneminder.com/).  I run it under Ubuntu and it works with my Samsung SmartCam.  ZoneMinder supports [many cameras](https://wiki.zoneminder.com/Hardware_Compatibility_List), and, even though mine was **not** in the list, I was able to get connected with the help of users on their support forum.

ZoneMinder is open source and provides [many features](https://zoneminder.com/features/) including:

- RTSP streams.
- Continuous recording and motion detection.
- Web based console to control the software.
- Email notification for events.

I've not tried to use it on a “scheduling” basis, so, I don't know if it supports that.  However, “scheduling” seems like something that can be set up in the OS.